# How prevent paper-toolbar element from being condens

Tags: polymer, toolbar

While scrolling, the paper-toolbar is condensed. How can I disabled this behaviour ?

**Not condensed**

[image: Not condensed]

**Condensed**

[image: Condensed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was two `<paper-scroll-header-panel>` :

- One for the menu bar
- One for the content

...and I was trying to modify the former instead of the latter.

The html tag for the content panel was written as following :

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" condenses keep-condensed-header>
```

The only thing to do was removing `condenses` :

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" keep-condensed-header>
```

**EDIT :**

Even better :

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" fixed>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using paper-header-panel? paper-header-panel is specifically made to make it easy to use the paper-toolbar to have a 'toolbar' as a fixed header that stays put while the rest of the content scrolls.

paper-header-panel is designed to work with paper-toolbar for this purpose, and it should just be a matter of wrapping your paper-toolbar and your scrolling content with a paper-header-panel:

```
<paper-header-panel>
    <paper-toolbar> <!-- Internally, paper-header-panel will project this into a header div -->
        <div>Toolbar stuff</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div>Main content stuff</div> <!-- Internally, paper-header-panel will project this into a scrolling div -->
</paper-header-panel>
```

Comment: Actually I was using the `paper-scroll-header-panel`. I replaced it with `<paper-header-panel>` but it did not work (Nothing displayed).
Maybe I could set a minimum height for the condensed `paper-scroll-header-panel`. I am investigating this way.

Comment: Paper header panel requires a that you set a height on either it or its parent, fyi